# How to get the size (memory size) of an image in iphone?

Tags: ios4

I'm using images in an iPhone application. I need to restrict the images so that those larger than 4MB cannot to be uploaded.

How can I check the data size of an image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the memory size of the image, we can use

NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
double size=[data length];

will give the size of the image in bytes.